# Не работает setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Изучаю React.js. У меня есть форма для добавления компонентов на страницу. Я делаю валидацию этой формы. При клике на кнопку  Add срабатывает функция onBtnClickHandler() которая получает значения  из инпутов формы и обновляет state. 
  В каждом инпуте у меня есть атрибут name, значение этого атрибута становится ключом, value из инпута становится значением это все у меня попадает в новый state. Форма работает хорошо. 
  Далее c помощью функции validate() я проверяю было ли что-либо введено в инпут и обновляю state. Для этого у меня есть объект objectItems, куда я записываю состояние своего инпута, nameМоегоИнпутаIsValid : true или false. Тоже все работает.
  У меня в objectItems есть еще свойство formIsValid, которое по умолчанию равно false. В функции validateData() я проверяю, чтобы this.state.objectItems значение всех nameМоегоИнпутаIsValid было true и хочу обновить state переписать formIsValid : true. Но стейт не обновляется, и я не понимаю почему.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import apiCall from '../../Api/mockedApi';
import CardsGenerator from './CardsGenerator';


class CardsContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: [],
      objectItems: {
        genderIsValid: false,
        priceIsValid: false,
        titleIsValid: false,
        imageUrlIsValid: false,
        formIsValid: false,
      },

    };

    this.deleteCard = this.deleteCard.bind(this);
    this.onChangeInput = this.onChangeInput.bind(this);
    this.onBtnClickHandler = this.onBtnClickHandler.bind(this);
    this.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
    this.validateData = this.validateData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    apiCall().then(
      (result) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: result,
        });
      },

      (error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          error,
        });
      },
    );
  }

  onChangeInput(event) {
    const { name } = event.currentTarget;
    const { value } = event.currentTarget;
    this.setState(state => ({ objectItems: { ...state.objectItems, [name]: value, [`${name}IsValid`]: this.validate(value) } }));
  }

  onBtnClickHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(state => ({ items: [...state.items, state.objectItems] }));
    console.log(this.state.objectItems);
    this.validateData();
  }

  validate(value) {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      return value.length > 2;
    } if (typeof value === 'number') {
      return value >= 0;
    }
    return value;
  }

  validateData() {
    const {
      genderIsValid, priceIsValid, titleIsValid, imageUrlIsValid, formIsValid,
    } = this.state.objectItems;
    if (genderIsValid === true && priceIsValid === true && titleIsValid && imageUrlIsValid === true) {
      this.setState(() => ({ objectItems: { formIsValid: true } }));
      // this.setState({objectItems:{formIsValid:true}})
    }
    console.log(genderIsValid, priceIsValid, titleIsValid, imageUrlIsValid, formIsValid);
  }

  deleteCard(e, index) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { items } = this.state;
    const newItems = items.filter((item, i) => i !== index);
    this.setState(() => ({
      items: newItems,
    }));
  }


  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    const itemColorBorder = () => this.state.objectItems.map(
      (item, index, arr) => (item === true ? 'green' : 'red'),
    );
    if (error) {
      return <div>No cards yet</div>;
    } if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {items.map(
          (item, index) => <Card info={item} index={index} del={this.deleteCard} />,
        )}
        <CardsGenerator id="cardGenerateForm" key={9379992} add={this.onChangeInput} submit={this.onBtnClickHandler} borderColor={itemColorBorder} disabled={this.state.objectItems.formIsValid} validate={this.validate} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default CardsContainer;
```

Comment: Может проста ваш метод `apiCall` не работает?

Comment: Работает,  у меня все отрисовывается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код в стиле

```js
this.setState({value});
console.log(this.state.value);
```

не даст желаемого результата, потому что `setState()` - это асинхронная операция.

Для того чтоб выполнить какой-то код после установки состояния компонента, можно передать callback вторым параметром:

```js
this.setState({value}, () => {
  // вот тут state уже находится в нужном состоянии
  console.log(this.state.value);
});
```

В случае кода из вашего примера это будет как-то так:

```js
this.setState(state => ({ items: [...state.items, state.objectItems] }), () => {
    console.log(this.state.objectItems);
    this.validateData();
});
```

Comment: Логика эта мне понятна. Я исправил код, но все равно не работает. Не пойму где ошибка или я неправильно validateData написал, или не так ее вызываю. Суть у меня такая у меня форма для генерации компонентов CardsGenerator, которая генерирует компонент Card. Я функцией onChangeInput проверяю ввел ли я что-нибудь в инпуты. Допустим я указал цену и  this.state.objectItems.priceIsValid : true и так все поля по аналогии. Потом после того как форма заполнена я должен изменить значение formIsValid с false на true, но этого не происходит.

Comment: ```onChangeInput(event) {
        const { name } = event.currentTarget;
        const { value } = event.currentTarget;
        this.setState(state => ({ objectItems: { ...state.objectItems, [name]: value, 
        [`${name}IsValid`]: this.validate(value) } }), () => this.validateData());
     }```

Comment: Ваш код выглядет норм. Можно убедиться что: 1. `validateData` вызывается 2. все поля валидные. Попробуйте дебаггером прогнать работу компонента шаг за шагом.

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо, только есть небольшие нюансы, но думаю разберусь

Comment: моя функция работает, но не добавляется валидация последнего инпута. Т.е. у меня  4 инпута. Когда я ввожу данные в каждый инпут у меня срабатывает функция валидации (моя this.validateData()), которую я вызываю в обработчике onChange. Но когда я дохожу до последнего ипута она не срабатывает, точнее срабатывает, но не так как надо. Т.е. у меня нету дальше инпутов и вроде бы обработчик не срабатывает. Последний инпут у меня выпадающий список select. И когда я выбираю один из предложенных вариантов значение в валидации не присваивается, но когда я по перебираю туда-сюда, то все начинает работать.