# Как в setState присвоить массиву другой массив?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Мне нужно массиву list в state присвоить значение равное массиву result. А получается почему-то пустой массив.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class Modal extends Component{
       constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state={
             list: []
           }
       }
       componentDidMount(){
             this.loagPageList();
       }
       loadPageList() {
               let result = ["1", "second"]
      
                this.setState({
                       list:  result
                })
                console.log("this.state.list: ");
                console.log(this.state.list);  //выдаёт пустой массив с length = 0
    }
     render(){
            return(
                 <div>1</div>
            )
     }
}
```

Comment: потому что setState асинхронна. Вы можете передать в качестве второго параметра setState, callback функцию и там вызвать консоль,

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает setState](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1019511/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-setstate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все работает, просто ты не там console.log написал.Вставь в render() например,
и увидишь что все меняется как ты хочешь.

```
render(){
        console.log("this.state.list: ");
        console.log(this.state.list);  //выдаёт пустой массив с length = 0
        return(
            <div>1</div>
        )
```

С чем связанно такое поведение?,если посмотреть в документацию то

```
setState(updater, [callback])
```

связанна с callback,соответственно когда ты требуешь результат в loadPageList() сразу, после setState.

Получается что setState еще не отработал,а console.log выводит прежний результат.Как то так, если я тоже правильно понял.